# 'flipud' colormap does not work

Tags: colormap

I am working on visualizing some stability areas of Runge Kutta Methods. now i have the issue, that i cant 'flip' the colours in the colormap.. I've been researching and trying out possible solutions..but all did not work. hope you guys can help me :)

here is my code:

```
function [g] = butcher(s1,c1,b1)

x0 = -3;
x1 =  3;
Nx = 301;

y0 = -3;
y1 =  3;
Ny = 301;

xv    = linspace(x0,x1,Nx);
yv    = linspace(y0,y1,Ny);
[x,y] = meshgrid(xv,yv);


z = x + i*y;
g=1+z*b1.*(1./(1-z*c1))*1;
gmag=abs(g);
contourf(x,y,gmag,[1 1],'k-');
cmap=flipud(colormap(gray));
colormap(cmap);
%colormap(flipud('gray'));
grid on;
axis equal;
end
```